# How to install freegeoip on my server

Tags: php, server

I want to install https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip On my Linux server. But i have no idea how to do that. Documentation is not very clear and i don't know anything about servers (I always thought cpanel->publichtml has all the stuff that matters). I know php very well but that doesn't help it.

So can someone give me little guidance. I am trying this for hours now, But still don't know where i am going. Please little help would make my day.

Comment: The instructions seem pretty comprehensive. What, specifically, don't you understand?

Comment: Hi, I have no idea, now  I am trying to install doker., If you understood how to install , could you write small answer for me to explain it.  i would really appreciate that.

Comment: 1. Go to the Docker website. 2. Pick the version appropriate for where you want to install it. 3. Read Docker's instructions

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Previously i was trying to  install compiled binaries. And it took  lots of time but didn't work. So i  giving a try to doker now. Thanks, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/releases/download/v3.2/freegeoip-3.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz) the latest release (currently 3.2) and untar on your server, make sure the binary has executable permissions then run the binary.

Run the following commands on your Linux server.

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/releases/download/v3.2/freegeoip-3.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar xvfz freegeoip-3.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz
cd freegeoip-3.2-linux-amd64
chmod +x freegeoip
./freegeoip
```

Once you've done that, you should see the following:

> 2017/06/23 14:26:21 freegeoip http server starting on :8080 
>   2017/06/23 14:26:21 database info: starting update 
>   2017/06/23 14:26:22 database info: finished update 
>   2017/06/23 14:26:23 database loaded: /tmp/freegeoip/db.gz

At this point you should be able to visit http://your-server-ip:8080/json/ and the service should be up and running.

*Note: The above steps were tested on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. This doesn't install the binary on your server, it only a runs the binary.*